# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-server-2012

I have a Godaddy hosted SQL Server database.

When I try to read from that database, I get an error as shown in the attached screenshot. Any help please ?

[The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv2lO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred due to wrong connection string ... Your application is not connecting to the database due to invalid path/connection string of database .. So just get the connection string copy it and replace it with the connection string specified in your app ... Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks For Your Comment This My ConnectionString <connectionStrings>
   
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=server_Name_Or_ip;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=User_Name;Password=My_Password;Integrated Security=false;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings> Some Times It's Work And Get Data But Most Time I Get This Error From Server

Comment: I Moved Database To My Local Machine It's Work Fine But When Connect to Godaddy Remote Server I Get The Error Please Help me !

Comment: when u moved ur database to godaddy your connection string is changed now so update your connection string according to the location of your database on goDaddy server